# Push row to certain sheet dependant on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a spreadsheet I have created

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HQJ2UK6R3QTLY9oeVe-PIaZngPN1luQAz633taE4Oo/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to make it so that if a task is "assigned to" a person from the drop down list on the "To Do" sheet, it pushes it to the relevantly titled person's sheet onedit.

Is there any way I can do this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is doable. You can refer to this page which might be helpful : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/hR40qh02UWE

Comment: Look at the documentation for the spreadsheet service: [Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Comment: @KRR that is very similar, but I need it to move to the sheet of the entry that's the name of the entry chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this post is connected to [this topic you posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934323/pushing-data-to-specific-sheets-depending-upon-cell-information/27939340?noredirect=1#comment44286390_27939340)
If it is, you can extend the script I provided earlier to also work for edits done on the sheet 'To Do'.

Please see, if this works for you:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = e.source,
    s = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    sheets = ["To Do", "Beau", "Derek", "Jay", "Steven", "Terence", "Victor"],
    ind = sheets.indexOf(s.getName());
if (ind === 0 && e.range.columnStart === 6 && e.range.rowStart > 4) {
    ss.getSheetByName(e.value).appendRow(
        e.range.offset(0, -5, 1, 6).getValues()[0])
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
} else if (ind > 0 && e.range.columnStart === 1 && e.value === 'yes') {
    ss.getSheetByName('Complete Tasks')
        .appendRow(e.range.offset(0, 0, 1, 7)
            .getValues()[0])
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
}
```

NOTE: I noticed you changed the 'e' to 'o'. This will lead to a non-working script. 'e' is not just a random letter, but represents an event object. [More info on event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: On a side note: I assumed the names to be entered in 'To Do' do alll have their on sheet. Maybe provide a drop down box in col E to avoid spelling mistakes.. Hope that helps ? Cheers, JP.

Comment: My word. You're a hero! And I did have a drop down box, but I kept stumbling across an issue. Every time the row gets pushed to it's new sheet, it deletes the data validation in that cell! Is there a way around that?  I've noticed it removes all formatting too!Thanks! @JPV